# Evaluating an hashmap in apache velocity

Tags: java, velocity

I have a template like this

```
$VAR_A

$VAR_B

#foreach ($obj in $TEMPLATE_ANOTHER) 

Value of VAR_A is $VAR_A
Value of REFVAR_A is $obj.get("A")

#if($VAR_A == $obj.get("A"))
 print success
#else
 print failure
#end

#end
```

When merging the context, I provide values for VAR_A = a1, VAR_B = b1
and for TEMPLATE_ANOTHE, I provide a HashMap with the following entries

```
("A", "a1")
("B", "b3")
("C", "c8")
```

On merging, the output expected is

```
Value of VAR_A is a1
Value of REFVAR_A is a1
print success
```

The == is simply not evaluating correctly and is printing failure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does it print exactly?

Comment: can you add the following to the template and print the updated output: $VAR_A.hashCode() - $obj.get("A").hashCode() - $VAR_A.equals($obj.get("A"))

Answer (score 1):

i think "==" uses identity comparison, you probably need to use equals() instead to actually compare the objects, i.e.

```
#if($VAR_A.equals($obj.get("A")))
...
```

Comment: +1.  Note that this is true of Java in general, and not specific to Velocity.

Comment: Is this really the solution? According to the [VTL reference guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/vtl-reference-guide.html) the `==` operator is meant to compare strings:
*The == operator can be used to compare numbers, strings, objects of the same class, [...]*

Comment: hmm, you're right, it seems velocity always uses "equals()" for "==", let me see if there is another thing that could be the reason here...